Why is it bitcoin.SE instead of cryptocurrencies.SE
With all of the altcoin rage and the random loss/gain of trust in bitcoin recently, why is this stackexchange named "bitcoin" instead of "cryptocurrencies"? I mean, it seems like most of the question are over the bitcoin protocol, which encompasses bitcoin and most altcoins, but some are specific to altcoins and some are specific to bitcoin. 

related: This site should be renamed

When the Bitcoin.SE site was launched in August 2011, the only viable cryptocurrency was Bitcoin. Even Litecoin wasn't released until October 2011. Namecoin had only existed for a couple of months (and arguably isn't really a cryptocurrency itself).
That's the reason why. Perhaps this site should be renamed to something more general, but that's a different question.

Actually, I read somewhere that the proposal started out named "Bitcoin and other Cryptocurrencies", which was shortened by SE staff to just "Bitcoin" when the site started into the beta. Source: In the comments here: http://meta.bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/345/5406
